# NP0 C0G X7R (Y5V?) Typical Leakage Currents?

Tags: capacitor, specifications, leakage-current

does anyone have some "typical" values or ballpark averages for the various SMT capacitor leakages?

I assume that if the leakage is dependent on the dielectric, then NP0's would be "best." But how does the typical NP0's leakage compare to say, an X7R? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading the data sheets?

Comment: In my limited experience, the data sheets give a maximum current, that can be a lot higher than what you measure.  But I've only looked at leakage in polarized caps.  (tant./ alum.)  Maybe your question should be, How to measure leakage in caps.

Comment: Well it would be straightforward to measure, and as Mr. Herold suggests, the datasheets give only maximums if anything, not typical values. But I have neither a set of equal-capacitance NP0/C0G/X7R/etc to "play with", nor the PCB to solder them to. It's hard to believe that there is no base-line out there. How are we supposed to pick a capacitor for a leakage limit - trial-and-error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used NP0s in circuits where pAs count.  X7Rs have much higher leakage.  Plus, the leakage can vary a LOT from part to part.

Comment: Just used some 16v 560uF polymer electrolytics in an (unrelated) switching regulator. Their ESR is 14mOhms, so they work very well, but the leakage was atrocious, measuring -40% to +20% over five units. (LC typ. 1.8mA!)